# SQL Server 2005 - Blocked Process Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I need to investigate a series of blocks and deadlocks that have been occurring randomly on our SQL 2008 server. I am the main developer on the site and do not have a DBA to lean on...

I am planning on using the Blocked Process Report in 2005 and enabling a trace.

What performace issues can I expect?  The DB server is for a website with moderate traffic and I want to minimize the impact the trace will cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Event Notification](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/07/18/Immediate-deadlock-notifications-without-changing-existing-code.aspx) method. it works in 2005 and 2008. it doesn't present any perf problem for detecting deadlocks